# Is there a way to show Source Blocks output value in a Bar Chart?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create a Bar Chart that will contain of Source Block Output. I was using the function Source.Size() but realized I need to call the output.

Do anybody have expertise on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm0i2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use `sourcePallets.count()`:
[image]

You can always see all possible methods by using code-complete (Ctrl+Space on Windows).

Also, the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/source.html#functions) lists all useful methods for you for all blocks, check it out:
[image]